# cmd line syntax to delete folder where file does NOT exist

Tags: cmd, rd

I need to delete all folders and subfolders where a specified file does NOT exist in the root but leave all files and folders if the specified file is found. The file will be in the root.
i.e.
c:\list\12345\1\1
12345 contains the txt file "complete", so leave this folder and file structure alone.
i.e.
c:\list\67891\1\1
67891 does NOT contain txt file "complete", so delete 67891 and all its subfolders and files.

I've tried nothing. I am completely new to cmd shell. Or maybe theres a util that will do this.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question... You say, 'If folder c:\list\1 contains a specified file, then remove c:\list\1 and then 'But if specified file IS found in root, then leave those folders and files'

So the folder should be removed, only if one of the subfolders has the file and not if the file is in the root folder?

What about empty folders? Your giving us two conditions that doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: Should it remove the folder if a specific file is found only within it's sub folders and not in the root folder?

Comment: So you want to keep a folder if that folder *and* all of its parents up to a specific root contain a certain file, is that correct? Otherwise that folder should be deleted, either on its own (when all the parents have the file but that folder doesn't) or along with a parent that doesn't have the file, right?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: rephrased the question. It doesnt matter if there is any content or if there are even subfolder. if that txt file exists, move on, if it doesnt exist, delete the root folder (where the file is) and all subfolders and files.

Comment: I'll try to write out the logic, I just dont know cmd enough to write the batch script. FOR EACH DIR in c:\list open DIR IF NOT EXISTS "complete.txt" REMOVE DIR c:\list\DIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** This is untested.  It creates `file.bat.txt` **for you to check** and then you can run it if it has the right folders in it.  After you check `file.bat.txt` and are happy with it then you can rename it to `file.bat` and run it to remove the folders.

What the code below does is: create a list of all paths to any file named complete.txt under c:\list and then compares `only the root folder` of every folder in the main folder.  If the root folder is not found in the list then it echoes the RD command to remove it into `file.bat.txt`

```
@echo off
set "folder=c:\list"
if not defined folder goto :EOF
dir "%folder%\complete.txt" /b /s /a-d >temp.tmp
del file.bat.txt 2>nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%folder%" /b /ad ') do (
find /i "%folder%\%%a" <"temp.tmp" >nul || >>file.bat.txt echo rd /s /q "%folder%\%%a"
)
:del temp.tmp
```

Comment: wow - awesome! Thanks for a great start! Its not creating the rd command file. I cant figure out (and I'm googling) why I am getting "not expected at this time" at || or >> (nul || >>file.bat.txt echo rd /s /q "%%a"). I've tried removing one at a time but I'm sure something is required here.

Comment: I had made a couple of typos and the findstr command hung, so I fixed it in the edit above.  It will create an RD command for every folder that doesn't match, so there will be multiple redundant RD commands but the `if exist` command will only execute the ones that are needed.

Comment: I've spent about 3 hours trying to put my mind around this and trying different things... the output file.bat.txt contains the entire directory list. I need it to contain what is NOT IN temp.tmp, and rd at the root level (there are entries like rd c:\list\12345\1 where I am wanting to delete at the root - rd c:\list\12345). Also, can you recommend a good site for the use of cmd, variables, switches, etc (all the stuff you are using here)? I find snippets but it would be nice to have (short of buying "cmd for dummies") if there was a comprehensive site dedicated to cmd. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My code is simple in operation but it doesn't remove all the duplicates from any deep directory path. In any case the `IF EXIST` will eliminate error messages if it tried to remove a folder that has already been deleted.  The difference in speed from eliminating the redundant lines would be miniscule, and would require more code.  It should NOT contain the entire directory list, as the find removes any parts of the tree that contains the files.

Comment: Ok I understand the deep directories. But the entire directory is in file.bat.txt: temp.tmp=c:\list\12345\complete.txt
c:\list\12345Copy\complete.txt (as expected) while file.bat.txt = if exist "c:\list\67891" rd /s /q "c:\list\67891"
if exist "c:\list\12345\1" rd /s /q "c:\list\12345\1"
if exist "c:\list\12345Copy\1" rd /s /q "c:\list\12345Copy\1"
if exist "c:\list\67891\1" rd /s /q "c:\list\67891\1". IE 67891 should not be in this file. I really appreciate this site and your help  -thank you

Comment: Try it now.  I wasn't quite on your wavelength with the earlier code.  This should leave every tree that contains a `complete.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /r "c:\list" %%f in (.) do ( 
        dir /s /b "%%~ff\complete.txt" >nul 2>&1 || echo rd /s /q "%%~ff" 
    )
    endlocal
```

Adapt as needed. When output to console is correct, remove the `echo` command before `rd` to remove the directories.

While `echo` command is present, the list of directories to delete will include complete branches, but when `echo` is removed, and `rd` is working, since the first parent in a disposable branch is removed, all his descendants are deleted in the same operation.